# How to dismiss Android Spinner drop down list programatically

Tags: android

I had a scenario where I am using spinner  in my app. A made spinner drop down list to open up directly using "performclick()" method . The drop down list is opened. Is there a way in which I can close it automatically or click an item from drop down list automatically so that the drop down list is dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Borg8's answer is the only solution that works!  Here is my version to add the spinner back.

```
if (spinner.getParent() == null){
  parent.addView(spinner);
  spinner.setLayoutParams(params);
  spinner.forceLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Spinner` does not expose any means to close it explicitly. If `setSelection()` does not have that effect, then you may need to write your own widget that gives you more control, or avoid trying to do this.

Comment: Is there any means that we can access the adapter of the spinner and click on the view of that adapter of our choice ?

Comment: @Android_programmer_camera: You can call `getAdapter()`, but you do not have a good way to get to the views it created, and I am skeptical that calling `performClick()` on one will accomplish your objective.

Comment: myspinner.performClick();
                    myspinner.setSelection(3);
                    View v = myspinner.getAdapter().getDropDownView(0, myspinner.getChildAt(0), myspinner); v.performclick() . But still its not working

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me and, for now, I don't see any reason why it will stop work.

If *spinner* is your spinner, then:

```
// get spinner layout and its parameters
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)spinner.getParent();
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = spinner.getLayoutParams();

// remove spinner from the layout - will dismiss its dropdown menu
parent.removeView(spinner);

// add spinner back and set same parameters
parent.addView(spinner);
spinner.setLayoutParams(params);
```

That's it